# Display of div is not working during postback?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, postback

Here I have a div tag in the master page header. While clicking on the href tag div is hiding during the postback. Heres my code:

```
  function setVisibility(id, visibility) {
     document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
     }
```

and

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Update" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <div runat="server" class="divSUBMenu" id="describe" style="width: 700px; height: 20px;
     font: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
     <div id="1" style="display:none;" >
     <font style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;">
     <a style="color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;" href="Page1.aspx" onclick="setVisibility('1','inline')">Page1</a>
    </font> 
     </div>
    <div id="2" style="display:none;" >
    <font style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;">
    <a style="color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;" href="Page2.aspx">Page2</a>
    </font>
    </div>

    <div id="3" style="display:none;" > <font style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;">
     <a style="color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;" href="Page3.aspx">Page3</a> 
</font> 
</div> 
</div> 
</ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

EDIT:Rendering html

```
<div id="Update">
<div id="describe" class="divSUBMenu" style="width: 700px; height: 20px; font: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<div id="1" style="display:none;">
<div id="2" style="display:none;">
<div id="3" style="display:none;">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to hide the `#describe` div on postback through the update panel?  If you are hiding something with your javascript function, it will not persist once your Update Panel refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript may not work as you are expecting if you are using UpdatePanel which is AJAX based.
Try to use ClientScript to register your script